# What is the fastest way (lowest number of keys pressed) to add attribute to html tag?

Tags: filetype-html

For example, cursor shall be at "*":

```html
<Typography
  gutterBottom
  component="h1"
  variant="h4"
  color="text.primary"
  sx={{mb: 3}}
>
  Che*ck this!
</Typography>
```

E.g. add `align="center"` to `Typography` tag with the fewest keystrokes possible. Is there a nice shortcut, instead of `<Esc>ko`, something like `cit`, but "add (attribute) to tag"?

Comment: is this a vimgolf challenge?

Comment: 1. "Lowest number of keys pressed" ≠ "fastest". 2. No, there is no such thing built-in. 3. This is the ideal use case for creating a custom mapping that does exactly what you want with the keystrokes you want. Let's see something that you tried.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It's the little tips, snippets, mentions I've found and researched on the net, that make my vim experience so pleasant and fast, e.g. `ci"`, `vipJ`, etc. So I thought it'd be legitimate to ask for help and if I overlooked something.

Comment: `ci"` and `vipJ` are not "tips" or "tricks" or whatever. They are basic functionalities available to anyone smart enough to learn Vim properly.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Esc</kbd>`kO` seems shortest: I can also come up with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>`?>?-`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>`?<`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`%O` and variations for robustness, but they're more strokes.

Now, you can map any one of those (in normal or insert mode) to make it a single keystroke. I recommend a `<buffer>`-local mapping, since this is specific to HTML-like (JSX?) code.

You could also use `input()` to get the name and value of the attribute, and insert the line from the mapping. Something like

```
function PutAttribute() abort
  const key = input('key: ')
  const val = input('val: ')
  const closer = search('>', 'bnW')
  const to_place = closer - 1 " guess, can do better
  const ind = repeat(' ', indent(to_place))
  if closer > 1
    return append(to_place, printf('%s%s=%s', ind, key, val))
  endif
  return 2
endfunction
```

Then map a call to `PutAttribute`, but beware warnings in `:help input()` about mappings which call `input()`.

Comment: Ty for the inspiration, `?>`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`i` is awesome I think and also works when tags are in a single line for example.